# Display RAZOR page instead of JSON format (C#, WebService)

Tags: c#, json, web-services, razor, data-binding

I have a controller with a method Get which returns `JSON` data:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(string name)
{
    var @books = await _booksService.BrowseAsync(name);
    return Json(@books);
}
```

When I run the WebService and get to **books** controller, it looks like:

[image]

Instead of display **JSON** data I want to have **RAZOR page**? 
How can I do it?

Comment: You need to return `View(@books)` and have the matching raxor view defined for the controller action.

Comment: do you have example of **matching raxor view**, some example?

Comment: You are returning a Json flow instead of a View. That's why your page shows JSON.

Comment: Have a look at any of the razor tutorials out there. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/razor-pages-start?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to return View instead of JSON

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: do you have any example how can I connect **view1.html** with controller?

Comment: @4est you can specify the view name like View("view1", model) to pass both

Comment: Here is the list of all the overload available for view method https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controller.view?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_Controller_View

Comment: @Mihir => thanks, after return **return View("books",@books)**, inside html, do I need to do somethink more or just use my json fields?

Comment: @4est That totally depends on how you want to display your data.

Comment: for now just simple div, as I need just understood how to it's connected

Comment: this ms guide will get you going https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/accessing-your-models-data-from-a-controller#strongly-typed-models-and-the--keyword

Comment: thank you @Mihir, I have tested and it's working fine

Answer (score 1):

You return a View("name"). Make sure that there is a .cshtml page with corresponding name in your views folder. Also you would need your controller class to inherit from `Controller` class rather than `ControllerBase` class